# NSUserDefaults not cleared after app uninstall on simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults, ios8, xcode6

this may sound real NOOB! I want to check if it's the second time the user enters my application, so to keep the run count I'm using `NSUserDefaults`. I have implemented the following code in my `rootViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"hello %ld", (long)[userDefaults integerForKey:@"runCount"]);

    if ([userDefaults integerForKey:@"runCount"] != 1) {
        //not the 2nd run
        [userDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"runCount"];
        NSLog(@"not 2nd run");
    } else {
        //second run or more
        NSLog(@"2nd run");
    }

    [userDefaults synchronize];
```

everything works fine, but the problem is that when I uninstall(delete and re-install) the application according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163798/is-data-stored-in-nsuserdefaults-persists-through-application-updates-and-on-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520800/are-values-stored-in-nsuserdefaults-removed-when-the-app-that-put-them-there-is) the data should be cleared, but it is not and after re-installing the app previous data is still showing up.
I'm running my app on iOS simulator using xCode6-beta and targeting the application on iOS 8

Comment: Have you tried testing on an actual device?

Comment: You need to clear it out manually on the simulator. [Here is how](http://stackoverflow.com/q/898498/335858).

Comment: please mark the correct answer so this question is no longer unanswered

Comment: @Reza:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedLists forKey:UserID]. My app crashes here in ios8 although works fine in ios6 and ios7. Here **selectedlists** in NSMutable Array and **UserId** is a string.

Comment: @Manthan this is some how a different issue, but I have faced the same problem somewhere else and the reason that caused the crash was Although the object I was saving for some key was `NSMutableArray` it was saved as a `NSArray` and changing it made my app crash... I recommend saving a `NSArray` and when you want to use it later casting it to `NSMutableArray` using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

I think this is due to a bug in the iOS8 Beta Simulator.

The expected behavior is that when the app is deleted, the NSUserDefaults for that app are deleted as well.

- However, NSUserDefaults are **NOT** deleted when you remove an app from the simulator.
- They are correctly deleted when you delete them from a physical device running iOS8.

A quick and annoying solution for now is to click, iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.

Xcode 9.2 with Simulator 10 still presents this issue. Menu option is now Hardware .. Erase All Content and Settings

I submitted a bug report btw

Comment: Tested it on iOS 8 GM and the bug is still existent. Very annoying.

Comment: They've yet to address my bug report either.. :/

Comment: I can also confirm this buggy behavior in Xcode 6 GM simulator and iOS 8 (12A365)!

Comment: It's possible to manually delete the plist file in which the `NSUserDefaults` are stored on a per-simulator basis.

Comment: This bug still persists in Xcode 6.0.1. +1 for the Reset Content and Settings from the iOS Simulator app.

Comment: yea and on top of this, my ios8 simulators are unable to boot since the GM install.

Comment: Reset Content and Settings is the best solution, thanks.

Comment: +1 confirmed in XCode 6.1. Can someone confirm this is a "simulator only" issue and the phone behavior will not change?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, it works correctly on a real device

Comment: Yes, it's only simulator issue on XCode6.1

Comment: Existing Open Radar link for who wants to follow the case: http://openradar.appspot.com/18540702

Comment: Looks like the bug is fixed on SDK 8.1 after update to XCode 6.1 (6A1052d)

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue.

If you have more than 1 app under the same group and all of them are using app groups (ON under capabilities), then you will have to remove all the apps from the device in order for the user defaults to be cleared.

Since the user defaults are shared, even if one of the app is on the device then it will not be deleted, as that app will be using the userdefaults.

Comment: Xcode 9.2 with Simulator 10 still presents this issue. Menu option is now Hardware .. Erase All Content and Settings.

Answer (score 14):

Since Reset Content and Settings is a nuclear option, you could consider two other options until the bug on the iOS 8/Xcode 6 GM simulator is addressed:

1. You could manually delete the plist file where the `NSUserDefaults` are stored. This is currently located at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*some_device_id*/Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.yourapp.plist`  It's a little tedious to find the right simulator to work with among the UUID directory names. **EDIT**: 2014-10-28 20-34-52 Correct path: 
   `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*some_device_id*/data/Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.yourapp.plist`
2. You could perform "surgery" on that plist (using a run script build phase perhaps) using [plistbuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) e.g.

`/usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "Set :BSDidMoveSqliteDb 0" path_to_plist`

Comment: You are missing /data/ after /*some_device_id*/

Answer (score 8):

For anyone facing the same issue.

If you have more than 1 app under the same group and all of them are using app groups (ON under capabilities), then you will have to remove all the apps from the device in order for the user defaults to be cleared.

Since the user defaults are shared, even if one of the app is on the device then it will not be deleted, as that app will be using the userdefaults.

Answer (score 4):

The code should work fine on the device.
Maybe some bugs in the simulator.

Try to Reset Contents and Settings for the Simulator.

Comment: Reseting Contents and Settings works alright, and I don't have a device at the moment to check. tnx :)

Answer (score 4):

it is a bug, and you can delete  NSUserDefaults with following code

```
 NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

Answer (score 2):

While this is still a bug another option could be to remove the specific key(s) in NSUserDefaults. Most of the time, when testing/developing, we only care about a few keys and not everything in NSUserDefaults. If you do only care about a few keys than I propose adding `removeObjectForKey`:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// ADD THIS TO SIMULATE CLEAN/EMPTY DEFAULTS, COMMENT OUT AFTER INITIAL EXECUTION.
// This will cause the TRUE case to be executed.
[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"runCount"]

NSLog(@"hello %ld", (long)[userDefaults integerForKey:@"runCount"]);

if ([userDefaults integerForKey:@"runCount"] != 1) {
    //not the 2nd run
    [userDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"runCount"];
    NSLog(@"not 2nd run");
} else {
    //second run or more
    NSLog(@"2nd run");
}

[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Adding `removeObjectForKey` simulates the first run of the app, commenting it out will simulate all subsequent app executions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i found the *.plist in the following directory:

[1] /Users/*SOME-USERNAME*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*SOME-DEVICE-ID*/data/Library/Preferences/SP.UserDefaultsTest.plist

**Problem:** Deleting the app in xCode 6(iOS 8 simulator) but the file stays on disk like mentioned above.

**Solution:** Deleting the located file from path [1] manually and the NSUserDefaults are gone.

So the annoying way to reset the simulator is no longer necessary.