# NSUserDefaults with iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, nsuserdefaults

Before iOS 8, if I uninstalled an app, the NSUserDefaults associated with that app would also be deleted.  Then if I reinstalled the app, the NSUserDefaults would be their initial values.

However, with iOS 8, even after I delete an application, when I reinstall it, the NSUserDefaults are saved between application installs.  They do not reset to their initial value.

Does anyone know if this is intentional?  Or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults not cleared after app uninstall on simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985825/nsuserdefaults-not-cleared-after-app-uninstall-on-simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bug in simulators.This bug also exist in prior to iOS8 beta4 on devices.But on devices this bug is resolved but it currently exist on simulators.They have also changed the simulator directories structure.If you **reset your simulator** it will work fine.On iOS8 devices it will also work fine.

Comment: +1. Yes, the bug relates to Simulators only as far as I tested too